# Appirater not asking to review

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, appirater

I am installing the Appirater app review library which can be found here:
https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater

I set these values in the Appirater.m just to test if it asks me to review:

```
static NSString *_appId;
static double _daysUntilPrompt = 30;
static NSInteger _usesUntilPrompt = 2;
static NSInteger _significantEventsUntilPrompt = -1;
static double _timeBeforeReminding = 1;
static BOOL _debug = NO;
static id<AppiraterDelegate> _delegate;
static BOOL _usesAnimation = TRUE;
static UIStatusBarStyle _statusBarStyle;
static BOOL _modalOpen = false;
```

and I configured my own AppDelegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ....   
    [Appirater appLaunched:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];
}
```

But when I opened the app twice, it didn't ask me to add the review.  Would anyone know what could have caused this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you set your appid for appraiter ?

Comment: @nsgulliver no i didnt get because i saw just trying to invoke the review dialog, and not have it go to the app store just yet.  Should I have set the app id?

Comment: I just changed this line: static NSString *_appId = @"my_app_id"; Was this what was necessary?

Comment: if you are using for testing purposes then you should turn on the debugMode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing purposes you should set the `static BOOL _debug = YES;`. Before adding the app to the `AppStore` make sure you set the `appID`.

Comment: actually it started suddenly working after I set the debug instead of the app id lol...not sure why

Comment: I mean I had the app id in there already a little while, but it only worked after I set the debug :)

Comment: AppId is needed for appStore:)

Answer (score 2):

Change `_daysUntilPrompt` to a lower value like `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this for testing in Appirator.h :

```
#define APPIRATER_DEBUG YES
```

Answer (score 1):

Appirater will do the following check to determine if a prompt is displayed:

```
 if (secondsSinceLaunch > secondsUntilPrompt 
 && launchCount > LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT)
```

Both conditions must be met. The number of days and the number of launches.

If you set your `DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT` to `0`, it will work. Alternately, if you set `APPIRATER_DEBUG` to 1, the prompt will always be shown.

Also note that I have a fork of appirater that has been enhanced quite a bit with improved code and new functionality such as memory usage improvements, localisation in several languages, and additional options for when to display the rating request dialog. [Here you](https://github.com/memmons/appirater) can check that.

Comment: by the way, should I set the full url for the review? Or just having the app id is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `[Appirater setDebug:YES];` and it will you ask every time you launch your app. No need to change Appirater.m or Appirater.h

Do not forget to set it back to NO before uploading to the AppStore